# How can I find “<html>“ in the Vim buffer?

Tags: vim

I want to search a HTML tag in my html file using Vim.
I tried `\<html\>` but it means search only the “html” word.
I don’t know how to find the greater or lower characters.

Comment: @jeremysprofile i got `E486: Pattern not found: <html>`

Comment: why there are 2 down votes? any explanations?

Answer (score 2):

Vim has 4 modes of regular expression interpretation:

- very no magic,
- no magic,
- magic and
- very magic.

The default is `magic` (check with `:set magic?`), which can be a bit surprising because some non alphanumeric characters have special regex meanings but not all. In particular `^$*.` do but most other characters do not. For example to match alternatives you'd have to escape the pipe character `this\|that` and `this|that` would match the literal string `"this|that"`.

In your case, `<` does not have a special meaning but `\<` does (beginning of a word). Searching for `<html>` will work, but when in doubt you can activate "very no magic" mode by prepending your search with `\V` (so `/\V<html>`) where every character matches the character itself. If and when you want to activate *all* regex features, you can activate "very magic" mode with lowercase `\v` (hence `/\v<html>` will search for the word "html").

Comment: i got: `E486: Pattern not found: <html>`

Answer (score 0):

In Normal mode, the `/` command searches forward (`?` — backward). Suppose we are at the top, and want to search forward. So, if we want to find a particular tag, like  “div” for example, we should type the following:

```
/\V<div>
```

Here `\V` turns on the ”very unmagic” mode in which a symbol has no any special meaning unless it is preceded by a backslash. (I use only the “very magic” and “very unmagic” modes and don’t use the “magic” and “unmagic” modes.)

If we want to find any html tag, i.e. something between angle brackets, we may type one of the following:

```
/\V<\[^<>]\+>
/\v\<[^<>]+\>
```

That will find and highlight all the tags including their attributes.

You may create a convenient keymap for the mode you prefer, for example:

```
nnoremap // /\V
```

Now, double hitting of `/` brings you to the search line with “very unmagic” mode.

Type `:help pattern` for more information.